# Printing light gray: which is better CMYK tints or spot tints?

Tags: pantone, print-production

I'm printing some banners and business cards with variations on a single design (banners coming from two different places, cards from a third place). The design has some very light grays in it: 4% 7% and 15% K.

For the banners it's possible for me to add a spot colour. So I am wondering, is there a better chance of the light grays showing up properly if I:

A: Set all the greys to be tints of Pantone Black.

B: Set all the grays to be tints of say, Cool Gray 3.

C: Set the very lightest gray (4%K) to be Cool Gray 1 at 100%. And keep the other grays (7% and 15%) as process tints.

D: Stick with the process black tints.

//

I'm designing the banners in Illustrator. The material is fabric for one and vinyl for the others. Unfortunately I think its too late to get physical proofs made.

Thanks very much,

Conor

Comment: Under practically all circumstances, a spot color will yield the best and most consistent result -- especially for such a light color. There is an option E: use 100% Cool Gray 1 plus some black for the darker tints. (Possibly hard to get right, though.)

Comment: Thanks, Jongware. Yeah, this is what I have been considering but I would be worried about the difference between the spot and the black tints. I might just go with the black tints but make them all a little darker.

Comment: Tints less than 10% are problematic to print. Matching colours on different materials is problematic. Matching colours on different finishes is problematic. You are creating the perfect storm for failure. Speak to your service providers for best practices to avoid sources of variability. The alternative is the finished job being refused and nobody gets paid.

Comment: How is the job being printed?  Digitally?  If so, then choosing a spot colour is pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just black (k) there will be *virtually* no difference -- a **tint is a tint.**

A 7% tint of black is equal to a 7% tint of [insert any Pantone color here]. Using spot colors does not improve a screen's ability to filter ink.

The *only* difference would be the *color of ink* being tinted, but the tints will be the same *quality*.

If you want to *remove* the tints, then yes, laying down a solid grey spot color, without any tint, will result in a better appearance than any tint will provide.

Comment: Scott some tints **may** have the possibility of being marginally better than others tough so a 50% tint of something with the right screen is better than 13% of some other color. but +1 anyway that's the general gist of it.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't comparing different *percentages*. Naturally it's easier to maintain a 50% screen than it is to maintain a 7% screen. Still, color has *nothing* to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are to create a light grey using CMYK, then use a percentage of (K) black with a % of (C) Cyan. You always want to use Cyan as opposed to Magenta because colour fluctuation of magenta is obvious.
All good offset and digital commercial printers use cyan.

Don't just use K, you'll find it's particularly inconsistent, grainy and streaky especially when printing digitally.

Comment: Hello Ash, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score -1):

Use a PMS cool gray and get 100% point to point to prevent open raster since a percentage of black will do that. But if you want that, go that way.